# Golang generic param

Tags: generics, go

Is there a way to use one function using a generic parameter instead of having two functions as shown below? I have Java background and looking for a way to have something like this

```
//Java
public Something doSomething(T val)

//Go
func (l *myclass) DoSomethingString(value string) error {
    test := []byte[value]
    // do something with test
    return err
}
func (l *myclass) DoSomethingInt(value int64) error {
    test := []byte[value]
    // do something with test
    return err
}
```

Comment: This seems like a use case for an interface. What is "something"?

Comment: I convert that into bytes and do some work..

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Go has no generics and no overloading. You can use a parameter of type `interface{}` and switch over it's real type:

```
func (*Test) DoSomething(p interface{}) {
    switch v := p.(type) {
        case int64:
            fmt.Println("Got an int:", v)
        case string:
            fmt.Println("Got a string", v)
        default:
            fmt.Println("Got something unexpected")
    }
}
```

[Link on Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M_LETzXXqN)

Comment: I had this problems on many projects. return intereface{} is way to do it (if you want to return different types with same function based os some switch case or if else). So @tkausl is checked and working of course!